# `Sequelize ORM` как взять специфический атрибут и переименовать его в запросе?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

У меня возникла такая проблема с работой в `node`. У меня подключена библиотека `Sequelize` для работы с базой данных `MySQL`.

И вот я хочу сделать запрос и взять только специфические атрибуты из таблиц переименовав их. Делаю все так как написано в [доке](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но после я получаю такой запрос, в катором имена атрибутов вообще другие. Они с названиями моделей.

Вот пример запроса и то что выдает мне запрос.

```
await User.findAll({
    attributes: ['id'],
    where: {id: userId},
    include: {
        model: StatusGroup,
        attributes: ['status'],
        include: {
            model: Organization,
            attributes: [['id', 'organization_id'], ['type_id', 'group_id']],
            where: {group_id: {in: userGroups}}
        }
    },
    raw : true
});
```

**Ответ**

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    'StatusGroupContacts.status': 0,
    'StatusGroupContacts.Organizations.id': 1,
    'StatusGroupContacts.Organizations.organization_id': 1,
    'StatusGroupContacts.Organizations.group_id': 1
  }
]
```

А сам запрос `mysql` выглидит так.

```
SELECT
  `users`.`id`,
  `StatusGroupContacts`.`status` AS `StatusGroupContacts.status`,
  `StatusGroupContacts->Organizations`.`id` AS `StatusGroupContacts.Organizations.id`,
  `StatusGroupContacts->Organizations`.`id` AS `StatusGroupContacts.Organizations.organization_id`,
  `StatusGroupContacts->Organizations`.`type_id` AS `StatusGroupContacts.Organizations.group_id`
FROM
  `user` AS `users`
  LEFT JOIN (
      `chat_user_group_status` AS `StatusGroupContacts`
      LEFT JOIN `organization` AS `StatusGroupContacts->Organizations`
    ON `StatusGroupContacts`.`user_id` = `StatusGroupContacts->Organizations`.`type_id`
    )
    ON `users`.`id` = `StatusGroupContacts`.`user_id`
WHERE `users`.`id` = 1
```

Но я хочу что бы запрос был вот так. (Ну по логике так как написано в доке.)

```
SELECT
  `user`.id, `organization`.id AS organization_id, `organization`.`type_id` AS group_id, chat_user_group_status.status
FROM
  `user`
  LEFT JOIN `chat_user_group_status`
    ON `user`.`id` = `chat_user_group_status`.`user_id`
  LEFT JOIN `organization`
    ON `chat_user_group_status`.`group_id` = `organization`.`type_id`
WHERE `user`.id = 1
```

Кто может подсказать мне что я делаю не так ? И как исправить это?

Comment: ORM лажа. пиши сырые запросы)

Comment: @muturgan еще не успел посмотреть как на `sequelize` написать запросы без `ORM` ))) . Хотел красивый код получить.)))

Comment: @muturgan спасибо большое. Помогло, Все так как в нормальных языках прогроммирования ))))))

Comment: Вам принципиально, чтобы именно в сгенерированном запросе были правильные алиасы или все-таки правильные имена полей в полученных объектах-моделях из базы? Думается второе важнее. Если так, то о чем беспокоиться? Задавайте нужные алиасы в `attributes` и будет вам счастье

Comment: @Anatoly принципиально что бы в ответе были правильные алиасы (и только те атрибуты которые хочу). Прочитайте вопрос полностю , я задаю атрибуты с алиасами. и смотрите в ответе что получаю. Конечно как сказал `@muturgan`  я так и сделал. Но хотелось бы понять зачем `ORM` работает не так как написано в доке.

Comment: В доке упрошенно дано просто. К тому же внешний вид SQL-запроса может зависеть от конкретной СУБД. Вы же понимаете, что могут быть одинаковые поля в разных таблицах, поэтому Sequelize всегда добавляет алиасы таблиц к полям, в том числе чтобы проще было потом раскидывать по объектам и группировать.

Comment: В целом SQL-запрос и не должен выглядеть красиво, он должен просто правильно работать. Если включить сокращение алиасов таблиц (иногда нужно для PostgreSQL, например), там и вовсе некрасиво будет выглядеть

Comment: @Anatoly если возмем `ORM laravel` то все что вы сказали должно и внем так быть. Я понимаю разницу между запросом и ответом. Я говорю про ответ.

Comment: Так а зачем включили опцию `raw` тогда? Выключите ее и посмотрите результат. Либо сгруппированные данные, либо плоский список.

Comment: @Anatoly `raw` просто дает мне массив вместо объекта. это не суть моего вопроса.